# Add common programs to Windows 10 path

Tags: windows-10

Is there somewhere I could find a script that could help me add common programs like firefox, word, ie  to the PATH so I could execute them in cmd?

Comment: IIRC, Chocolatey used once to have one common directory where it installed  shortcuts to all installed programs. So you could add this one directory to PATH.

Comment: Control panel->System->Advanced system settings, TAB `Advanced` and on the bottom click button `Environment Variables` where you can adjust/add/remove content of `PATH` variable

Comment: If you don't know about Chocolatey, definitely have a look.

Comment: Is there a reason you're unable to do this manually? Scripts and such as useful for when you know exactly what you want and need to do it multiple times on multiple computers. You don't have a thorough list ("common programs like...") and you're only doing this once.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the program to the following key in the registry:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\

1. Inside of "App Paths" create a key with the name of the program + extension that should run by only typing it's name in the run or command prompt.
2. Define the value data of the default string value equal to the complete path to the program that should run

ex: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

3. In the key that you created, create a string value called "Path" and define it's value data as the path to the programs folder that you want to run (without including the actual program just the path to the folder).

ex: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application

You can also include the path to the program by including the path to the program in the %path% variable.

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder someplace meaningful on your computer: `D:\files\pathcmd`

Open command prompt as administrator and run the following to add this folder to the PATH: `setx /M PATH "%PATH%;D:\files\pathcmd"`

Now create any application shortcuts you desire inside this folder, naming them something meaningful. Back when I did this I created a plethora of two or letter acronyms. For instance, the shortcut to Firefox was named "ff" and so I could open Firefox by opening Run and typing "ff".

Comment: This is the method I use but is it a permanent solution or does the `PATH` reset after some n number of reboots?

Comment: PATH does not reset. PATH may be modified, but in my experience, processes don't remove entries from PATH unless they are viral/bad processes.